# Using a pointer or not

Tags: c++, pointers

Will there be a difference between the following two ways of calling a function from an instance? Which is better?

```
    Motor M;
    M.moveToPosition(Speed, TargetPosition);

    Motor *M;
    M->moveToPosition(Speed, TargetPosition);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try the second?! It's UB to dereference an uninitialized pointer and I'd be surprised if this runs without problems.

Comment: @Marwan Dessouki it does compile indeed, but it won't run as expected.

Comment: @daknok_t: It *could* run as expected, but that's very unlikely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your second version has [Undefined Behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), because the pointer is uninitialized!

You can dynamically allocate an object of type `Motor`(i.e. allocate it on the heap):

```
Motor *M = new Motor;
M->moveToPosition(Speed, TargetPosition);
...
delete M;
```

[Smart Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) will help you avoid to have to remember to delete objects allocated on the heap.

As for which is better, I am afraid it depends a lot on the context. Usually in C++ you should prefer automatic objects (on the stack) to dynamic objects (on the heap) unless you have a definite reason for the contrary.

Comment: It would be better to point to M via a smart pointer (std::unique_ptr).

Comment: @MarcinHoppe: I was on my way of adding that piece (and more) while you were commenting :)

Answer (score 2):

The first method will call the `Motor` constructor; the second method won't and the pointer will be uninitialized.

In C++, stay away from pointers where possible. Use the first method here.

If you want to dynamically allocate the motor, use this:

```
std::unique_ptr<Motor> M(new Motor);
M->moveToPosition(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same, but using pointers you'd be able to dynamically create and destroy objects (i.e. in loops), perform operations on arbitrary number of objects, take advantage of the polymorphism, and so on.

Comment: ... and get some really cool memory leaks if you're not very cautious! :)

Comment: ".. come great memory leaks?" ^^